# How to use variables from test data on the the test description [(it.each)]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have the following code:

```
it.each([
    { property: 'nice test', expectedResult:'nice test' },
    { property: 'failed test', expectedResult: 'nice failed test' },
  ])('Should property and expectedResult be the same for property: $property', ({ property, expectedResult }) => {
    expect(property).toBe(expectedResult);
  });
```

How can I use the `property` argument on the test description?

*Example when running:*

```
Running > "Should property and expectedResult be the same for property: 'nice test'"
Running > "Should property and expectedResult be the same for property: 'failed test'"
```

Comment: Where is the `sport` variable defined?

Comment: @Camilo My bad. I change the description to be a little bit more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [test.each(table)  docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout)

> `table: Array` of Arrays with the arguments that are passed into the test fn for each row. If you pass in a 1D array of primitives, internally it will be mapped to a table i.e. `[1, 2, 3] -> [[1], [2], [3]]`

Try it like this:

```
it.each([
  ["nice test", "nice test"],
  ["failed test", "nice failed test"],
])(
  "Should property and expectedResult be the same for property: %s",
  (property, expectedResult) => {
    expect(property).toBe(expectedResult);
  }
);
```

---

OR: you can use `describe.each` to destruct the object in the upper scope and use it in template literal

```
describe.each([
  { property: 'nice test', expectedResult:'nice test' },
  { property: 'failed test', expectedResult: 'nice failed test' },
])('description', ({ property, expectedResult }) => {
  it(
    `Should property and expectedResult be the same for property: ${property}`,
    () => {
      expect(property).toBe(expectedResult);
    }
  );
})
```

[working example](https://replit.com/@StefanTeneff/so-76284162#variant2.test.js)